# Detect other items with same class other than with not(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, eslint

There are situations where it comes very handy to select all items with the same class except the current one:

```
$('.checkbox_handler').not(this).prop('disabled');
```

which works well. 
But now I've been running into a little issue with `this` (pun intended). I'm using [ESlint](http://eslint.org/) for any JS/jQuery linting with [this](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-invalid-this.html) rule enabled. Since then I'm constantly getting `no-invalid-this Unexpected 'this'` errors.

My question now: Is there any way around using `.not(this)` to detect any same classes which are not the current element. Or am I'm not seeing the bigger picture?

**Edit:** As requested more code to show

```
{
  otherFunctions: function() {},

  disableInput: function(selector) {
    $(selector).on('change', function() {
      $('.checkbox_handler').not(this).prop('disabled', function(i, value) {
        return !value;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Full markup. All within an object in which I'm iterating through the functions.

Comment: Can you provide the logic in which it's complaining about the usage of 'this'?

Comment: @Taplar the logic is the `not(this)` example above

Comment: No, 'this' is defined (or not) by it's context.  I want to see the context in which you are trying to use 'this' that the rule is trying to keep you from doing so.

Comment: Just a workaround, no valid solution for this problem exist: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/632#issuecomment-139816369 - I recommend disabling this rule checks.

Comment: please show your work. it would help answer the problem

Comment: @BrainFooLong how comes you are recommending to disable it? Better save than undefined.

Comment: If it truely is an idiosyncrasy with the ESLint there are various workarounds you could do.  Single elements with event handlers can be cached and their variables used.  Most iterating methods such as each() and map() will pass in an index or the actual object that is being used that can be references.  Events have a event.target that references the source element (believe that's the right property).  All of these are possibly solutions, but to know we need to know the context of your issue.

Comment: @Taplar see edited OP

Comment: It sounds like `ESLint` doesn't understand that jQuery binds the context when it calls its callback functions. There's nothing wrong with your use of `this`, ESLint is wrong to complain.

Comment: @supersize Generally i would say yes, but for the jquery case that uses `this` for the current context, which is perfect imho, ESLint have problems with it, so i would not struggle with such a "non-problem" imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so your js looks valid.  What I would suggest is to put 'e' or 'event' as the parameter to your handler and reference e.target for your 'this'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: Okay that sounds pretty reasonable to me and works in this case. Nevertheless I have a few cases where I cannot rely on `e.target` and might need to go the extra miles with @BrainFooLong s comment above.